# Send More Money Puzzle in Python

Tags: python

A famous puzzle follows.
SEND + MORE = MONEY

Substitute each letter in the equation with a single integer 0-9 (no duplicates) such that the addition is correct.  Write a program to solve this puzzle.  Hint:  Brute force works well {try all possibilities}.

Here's my code so far:

```
def solution():
    letters = ('s', 'e', 'n', 'd', 'm', 'o', 'r', 'y')
    for s in range(9, 0, -1):
        for e in range(9, -1, -1):
            for n in range(9, -1, -1):
                for d in range(9, -1, -1):
                    for m in range(9, 0, -1):
                        for o in range(9, -1, -1):
                            for r in range(9, -1, -1):
                                for y in range(9, -1, -1):
                                    if len(set((letters))) != len(letters):
                                        send = 1000 * s + 100 * e + 10 * n + d
                                        more = 1000 * m + 100 * o + 10 * r + e
                                        money = 10000 * m + 1000 * o + 100 * n + 10 * e + y

                                        if send + more == money:
                                            return send, more, money

print(solution())
```

But it isn't working. It gives no output. How can I fix this?

Comment: `len(set((letters))) != len(letters)` is invariant and never true. What is it for?

Comment: @Shankar That's not happening, though.

Comment: @Shankar - No such string multiplication is taking place.

Comment: I'm not sure what to use to meet the uniqueness requirement.

Comment: In keeping with the brute-force nature of your code, consider adding `if e == s: continue` at the top of the `e` loop, and something like `if n in (s, e): continue` in the `n` loop, and ... and `if y in (s,e,n,d,m,o,r): continue` at the top of the `y` loop.

Comment: backtracking  w/ most constrained ordering for vas, least constrained for values https://gist.github.com/elliott-beach/4f429d062f47394ebbcb57a454fee638:

Answer (score 5):

with uniqueness requirement and search for all solutions:

```
def solutions():
    # letters = ('s', 'e', 'n', 'd', 'm', 'o', 'r', 'y')
    all_solutions = list()
    for s in range(9, -1, -1):
        for e in range(9, -1, -1):
            for n in range(9, -1, -1):
                for d in range(9, -1, -1):
                    for m in range(9, 0, -1):
                        for o in range(9, -1, -1):
                            for r in range(9, -1, -1):
                                for y in range(9, -1, -1):
                                    if len(set([s, e, n, d, m, o, r, y])) == 8:
                                        send = 1000 * s + 100 * e + 10 * n + d
                                        more = 1000 * m + 100 * o + 10 * r + e
                                        money = 10000 * m + 1000 * o + 100 * n + 10 * e + y

                                        if send + more == money:
                                            all_solutions.append((send, more, money))
    return all_solutions

print(solutions())
```

Comment: This works great! How can I add a for loop at the end to return all the possible solutions for the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I could not resist to write a little more concise brute-force solution since I never heard of the puzzle before.

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

a, b, c = 'SEND', 'MORE', 'MONEY'

for comb in combinations(range(10), 8):
    for perm in permutations(comb):
        d = dict(zip('SENDMORY', perm))
        f = lambda x: sum(d[e] * 10**i for i, e in enumerate(x[::-1]))
        if f(a) + f(b) == f(c):
            print "{} + {} = {}".format(f(a), f(b), f(c))
```

Note that I did not exclude the possibility of `S -> 0` or `M -> 0` here.

**EDIT**: Similar, but using a generator and neglecting replacements that would lead to leading zeros.

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

def replacements(): 
    for comb in combinations(range(10), 8): 
        for perm in permutations(comb): 
            if perm[0] * perm[1] != 0: 
                yield dict(zip('SMENDORY', perm))

a, b, c = 'SEND', 'MORE', 'MONEY'

for replacement in replacements(): 
    f = lambda x: sum(replacement[e] * 10**i for i, e in enumerate(x[::-1])) 
    if f(a) + f(b) == f(c):
        print('{} + {} = {}'.format(f(a), f(b), f(c)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting lists to sets will only change their length if they have non-unique elements.
Check how sets work: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

From [community guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and
>   any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. The
>   first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will
>   see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible.

Answer (score 0):

@ siwica: your 'fast' solution provides a list of multiple results, so I propose a change in your second last line:

```
    if (f(a) + f(b) == f(c)) & (len(a) == len(str(f(a)))) & (len(b) == len(str(f(b)))):
```

so, I have no rights to comment, which is why I write this 'answer'

Comment: It has multiple solutions since I assumed `M -> 0` would be a valid replacement. The problem did not clearly exclude this option.

If no leading zeros are allowed you would check for this case right at the beginning of the loop though and not at the point that you suggested.

Also, I did not say my code was fast but only that it is concise. Those terms aren't always related.

Answer (score 0):

first we can get m = 1, use permutations to avoid same number appear

```
from itertools import permutations 

perm = permutations([0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 7)

for i in perm:

    if((i[0]*1000 + i[1]*100 + i[2]*10 + i[3] + 1000 + 100*i[4] + 10 * i[5] + i[1]) == (10000+1000*i[4]+i[2]*100+i[1]*10+i[6])):

        print(i[0]*1000 + i[1]*100 + i[2]*10 + i[3])
        print(1000 + 100*i[4] + 10 * i[5] + i[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with list comprehension (constraint programming):

```
[(send, more, money) for send in range(1023,9877) for more in range(1023,9877) for money in [send+more]
  if send + more > 9999
    and str(send)[1] == str(more)[3]
    and str(money)[:4] == str(more)[:2] + str(send)[2:0:-1]
    and len("".join(set(str(money) + str(send) + str(more)))) == 8]
```

- `send` and `more` are both 4 digit numbers
- `money` is a 5 digit number
- `send` and `more` have `e` as common digit
- the first 4 digits in `money` must match the respective ones in `send` and `more`
- there must be 8 different digits in total

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations

def solve_cryptarithmetic():
    # Define the letters and possible digits
    letters = ('S', 'E', 'N', 'D', 'M', 'O', 'R', 'Y')
    digits = range(10)
    
    # Generate all possible permutations of digits for the letters
    for perm in permutations(digits, len(letters)):
        sol = dict(zip(letters, perm))
        
        # Check for leading zeros
        if sol['S'] == 0 or sol['M'] == 0:
            continue
        
        # Calculate the values for SEND, MORE, and MONEY
        send = 1000 * sol['S'] + 100 * sol['E'] + 10 * sol['N'] + sol['D']
        more = 1000 * sol['M'] + 100 * sol['O'] + 10 * sol['R'] + sol['E']
        money = 10000 * sol['M'] + 1000 * sol['O'] + 100 * sol['N'] + 10 * sol['E'] + sol['Y']
        
        # Check if the equation holds true
        if send + more == money:
            print(f"  SEND: {send}")
            print(f"  MORE: {more}")
            print(f"  MONEY: {money}")
            return sol

# Call the function
solution = solve_cryptarithmetic()
```