# Task substitution of numbers to letters

Tags: python

I can't optimize the solution of such a problem (it needs to be done in 30 seconds):

Letterometrics are puzzles in which each letter must be matched with a digit in such a way that the proposed identity is fulfilled.
For example , a letter meter,
SEND+MORE=MONEY
it can be solved if we match letters with numbers as follows:
O - 0, M - 1, Y - 2, E - 5, N - 6, D - 7, R - 8, S - 9
As a result, we get the correct identity 9567+1085=10652.
The input to your program is a letter meter, in which the sum of two numbers is to the left of the equal sign, and one number is to the right. You need to deduce his solution. Note that the number cannot start from zero.

I despaired and came to the forum.
input data for debugging: THERE+ARE=RISKS, GREEN+ORANGE=COLORS, ELVIS+PRESLEY=POSTERS, DCLIX+DLXVI=MCCXXV, COUPLE+COUPLE=QUARTET.
Thank you in advance

I solved it using itertools.permutations, but each time the execution time is different (from 0.1 sec to 109 sec). The code is attached:

```
from itertools import permutations
 
s = input().replace('+', ' ').replace('=', ' ')
s2 = set(s.replace(' ', ''))
s = s.split(' ')
otv = -1
 
for i in permutations(range(10), len(s2)):
    y = dict(zip((list(s2)), i))
    if int(y[s[0][0]]) == 0 or int(y[s[1][0]]) == 0 or int(y[s[2][0]]) == 0:
        continue
    if int(''.join(map(str, [y.get(key) for key in s[0]])))+int(''.join(map(str, [y.get(key) for key in s[1]]))) == int(''.join(map(str, [y.get(key) for key in s[2]]))):
        otv = ' '.join('{} {}'.format(key, val) for key, val in sorted(y.items()))
        break
 
print(otv)
```

I tried to speed it up and make it through slices, but that didn't help either:

```
from itertools import permutations
 
s = input().replace('+', ' ').replace('=', ' ')
s2 = list(set(s.replace(' ', '')))
s3 = list(s)
s = s.split(' ')
otv = -1
 
for i in permutations(range(10), len(s2)):
    if i[0] == 0 or i[s2.index(s[1][0])] == 0 or i[s2.index(s[2][0])] == 0:
        continue
    y = dict(zip(s2, i))
    zy = [str(y[i]) for i in s3 if i.isalpha()]
    if int(''.join(zy[:len(s[0])])) + int(''.join(zy[len(s[0]):len(s[0])+len(s[1])])) == int(''.join(zy[len(s[0])+len(s[1]):])):
        otv = ' '.join('{} {}'.format(key, val) for key, val in sorted(y.items()))
        break
 print(otv)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send More Money Puzzle in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450302/send-more-money-puzzle-in-python)

Comment: @A-_-S Are any solutions there general and fast enough?

Comment: well didn't read all of them.

Comment: There are many heuristics one can do (like start assigning the most valuable digits first (S,M - in send more Money for example) - and than search for higher lower assignments